# setDefaultOptions VS. static options VS. options in setRoot

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Using **Wix's** react-native-navigation, what's the difference between setting layout options using these methodologies?

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
  topBar: {
    background: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
});
```

vs.

```
static options(passProps) {
  return {
    topBar: {
      background: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  };
}
```

vs.

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        children: [{}],
        options: {
          topBar: {
            background: {
              color: 'red'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

What are some reasons/cases/etc to define options statically inside a component, versus initializing a root with options? And what are the functional differences/what happens behind the scenes with these different ways?

Answer (score 0):

`setDefaultOptions` are default options that apply to all screens and all roots that will ever be created.
`static options` is defined per screen and override defaultOptions but do not apply for all screens
`setRoot` apply for this root only